# jQuery: Animate div from position fixed UP to another DIV

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

For some reason the DIV I want to animated is animating from the top down... I want to animate it from where it is UP to the end destination.

The DIV is starting as `position: fixed` to the bottom of the page.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
var div2Pos = $("#feature-header-wrapper").position();
$("#123456").css('position', 'absolute');
$("#123456").animate({top: div2Pos.top}, 1000);
```

Comment: Where is it coming from? The bottom of the page? Please add more information.

Comment: It's fixed to the bottom of the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is what you want:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/Q6KNk/

jQuery:

```
var div2Pos = $("#div2").position();
$("#square").css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: $("#square").position().top,
    left: $("#square").position().left
});
$("#square").animate({
    top: div2Pos.top
}, 1000);​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="square">Lorem Ipsum...</div>
<div id="div2">Lorem Ipsum...</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightBlue;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
#div2 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightGreen;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Basically it gets `div2`'s position then sets `#square` to it's current position but using absolute instead of fixed positioning so that the animation occurs instead of it jumping to the top.

**NOTE:** This will not work if `square` is inside of a relatively positioned element!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. But mine is in a duckhunt game so the animation fires several times and I thought it might help you to know it only happens the first time. After that, the div I'm animating retains the position I give it and animates from the bottom up. So if I have to...I'm guessing I can just add an extra little animation that does nothing. Hopefully I can find something less banal but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can mess around with something like this

```
       $("#123456").animate({top: '-=300px'}, 1000);
```

this will animate to 300px less , moving it up (I think that is what you wanted)